# Order of a group and order of its elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My question:

If $G$ is a group of order $p^k$ where $p$ is prime and $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.
Show that every $g \in G$ has order $|g| = p^j$ for some $j\in \mathbb{Z}^+$

My reasonings:

By Lagrange's theorem, the order of an element must divide the order of the group. thus, this means that every element in $G$ can have order $p^j$ since the only divisors of $p^n$ are: $p^0,p^1,...p^{n-1}$. However, I don't know how we prove that $j$ is a positive integer. would it be wrong to assume that $j$ is positive by the definition of order?

Comment: It is not the element which is $p^k$, it is the order of the element. Also you're correct that the order $j$ cannot be negative. However the identity element of your group has order $1=p^0$ so in your notation can only say $j \ge 0.$

Comment: Order of a group is the cardinality of the underlying set.

Comment: @coffeemath so if i understand correctly. j doesnt have to be a positive integer. it can also be zero because the identity element has order 1 which is only the case if j = 0

Comment: correction [to late to edit comment] in my comment above I referred to "the order $j$", however in the notation of the OP the element order is $p^j$

Comment: @user20194358 to your last query, yes, $j$ can be $0$. But keep in mind the order of an element cannot be zero, since it is the number of elements of subgroup of a group which is generated by a particular element. [any subgroup has the identity element in it.]

Comment: @coffeemath okok i understand. so the statement is false when it says for a positive integer j.

Comment: MathJax works in the title section, too, don't you know?

Answer (score 1):

Every group has an identity element $1$ with order $1=p^0$. For all $g\neq 1$ in $G$, we have that the order of $g$ is not $1$, otherwise $g$ is the identity element. As you mentioned already, the rest of the elements have order which divides $|G|$, so the rest of the elements have order $p^j$ for $j\in\{1,...,k\}$.